# How do i implement pagination and search to suit passing the data to the server side

Tags: javascript, html, forms, fetch-api, ajaxform

Please am kinda still in the beginner level of what am actually doing, and i need assistance with the main issue, improvement,suggestions and advice...
Well i have this page that has a form, containing a list of students to be selected for an assessment. The list of students is fetched from server using an ajax call, but first, every time the page is loaded, the data does not get immediately shown not until 5 or more seconds later and it makes the page looks like it needs some fixing.
Secondly the form on this page contains a list of students with options to check/uncheck which student you want to send to the server side, i made the default as checked for all, but with the kind of pagination i implemented, when i click on the next button to check/uncheck a student, it does not keep record of what i did on the previous page, so is it with my search implementation. its my wish if someone can implement it using fetch api, i would appreciate it.... here is my code for the page containing the form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/w3.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/global.css">
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/studentofferingsubjectform.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="body" class="w3-light-grey">
        <%
            HttpSession ss = request.getSession();
            if(ss.getAttribute("staffId")== null){response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");}
            Integer taId = (Integer)ss.getAttribute("taId");
            Integer qId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("questionRepoId"));
            ss.setAttribute("qId", qId);
         %>
        <div id="preloder">
           <div class="loader"></div>
        </div>
        <header class="w3-container main-header w3-border-bottom w3-top">
            <div class="w3-left w3-padding-small">
                <button class="w3-btn w3-hide-large w3-white w3-padding-small w3-border-0">&Congruent;</button>
                <img src="images/Graduation Cap_48px_1.png" alt="logo" class="w3-image">
                <h3 class="w3-text-white">
                    My School
                </h3>
            </div>
        </header>
        <nav class="w3-sidebar w3-collapse w3-animate-left w3-bar-block w3-white w3-border w3-border-right">
            <div style="padding-top: 6px;">
                <div class=" w3-border-bottom w3-border-light-grey">
                    <button class="w3-button w3-row w3-block w3-hover-none w3-padding-16 accordion">
                        <div class="w3-col s5">
                            <img src="pictures/${picture}" style="width: 75px; height: 75px;" class="w3-circle w3-image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="w3-col s6">
                            <div class="maketofit">
                                <div>${name}</div>
                                <small class="w3-text-gray">${role}</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w3-col s1">
                            <div class="w3-margin-top">
                                &blacktriangledown;
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </button>
                    <div id="profile" class="w3-container w3-hide">
                        <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button " href="staffviewprofile.jsp">My Profile</a>
                        <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button " href="staffeditprofile.jsp">Edit Profile</a>
                    </div>         
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-large w3-margin-bottom w3-dark-grey w3-hover-opacity w3-clear">
                    Close Menu
                    <span class="w3-right">
                        x
                    </span>
                </a>
                            <div class="w3-container">
                                <a class="w3-button w3-block w3-margin-top w3-round w3-border w3-border-blue w3-hover-blue w3-text-gray w3-hover-text-white" href="staffdashboard.jsp">
                                    <img src="images/Dashboard_20px_1.png">
                                    <span class="w3-padding-small w3-hover-text-white">DashBoard</span>  
                                </a>
                                <a class="w3-button w3-block w3-margin-top w3-round w3-border w3-hover-border-indigo w3-text-gray w3-hover-indigo" href="staffmessages.jsp">
                                    <img src="images/Chat_20px.png">
                                    <span class="w3-padding-small w3-hover-text-white">Message</span>  
                                </a>
                                <a class="w3-button w3-block w3-hover-text-white w3-hover-border-black w3-margin-top w3-hover-black w3-text-gray w3-round w3-border" href="staffsettings.jsp">
                                    <img src="images/Settings_20px_1.png">
                                    <span class="w3-padding-small w3-hover-text-white">Settings</span>  
                                </a>
                                <a class="w3-button w3-block w3-hover-text-white w3-text-gray w3-margin-top w3-hover-border-red w3-hover-red w3-round w3-border" href="logout">
                                    <img src="images/Shutdown_20px.png">
                                    <span class="w3-padding-small w3-hover-text-white">Logout</span>  
                                </a>
                            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="w3-overlay w3-hide-large w3-animate-opacity" style="cursor:pointer;" title="close side menu"></div>
        <div class="w3-main">
            <h2 class="w3-text-grey">DashBoard</h2>
            <h6>
                <a href="teacheraddassessment.jsp?id=<%=taId%>" class="w3-text-blue">
                    <span id="urlsubjectname"></span>: <span id="urlclassname"></span> - Assessment Details
                </a>
                <img src="images/Forward_20px_1.png" width="15" height="15" class="w3-image">
                <span class="w3-text-grey">
                    Add Students
                </span>
            </h6>
            <div class="w3-row w3-card w3-white w3-padding-16 alt1" id="cardA">
                <header class="w3-container">
                    <form class="w3-left w3-display-container">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="w3-input w3-border" id="search">
                        <img src="images/icons8_Search_20px.png" class="w3-display-right w3-padding-small">
                    </form>
                    <form class="w3-right w3-medium" id="form1" method="POST" action="AddAssessment">
                        <button class="w3-button w3-teal w3-round w3-padding-small">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </header>
            </div>
                    <input value="<%=taId%>" type="hidden" id="taId">
                <section class="w3-section w3-white w3-card alt1" id="container">
                    <table class="w3-table w3-bordered w3-border w3-text-gray">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>#</td>
                                <td>IMAGE</td>
                                <td>ROLL NO</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div>Page: <span><b id="page"></b></span></div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w3-center" colspan="2">
                                        <div class="w3-padding-small" id="paginationBtn">
                                            <a href="#" id="btn_prev">
                                                <span class="w3-hide-medium w3-hide-small w3-button w3-round-small w3-light-green w3-text-white">Prev</span>
                                                <span class="w3-hide-large w3-button w3-round-small w3-padding-small w3-border w3-border-light-green">❮</span>
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="#" id="btn_next">
                                                <span class="w3-hide-medium w3-hide-small w3-button w3-round-small w3-light-blue w3-text-white">Next</span>
                                                <span class="w3-hide-large w3-button w3-round-small w3-padding-small w3-border w3-border-light-green ">❯</span>
                                            </a>     
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w3-right datatable">
                                        <div>Total: <span><b id="totalCount"></b></span></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    <div id="emptyTableMsg"></div>
                </section>
            <footer class="w3-container w3-padding-16">
                <p class="w3-opacity">&copy; 2020 TegaConcept, All Rights Reserved</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my studentofferingsubjectform.js code below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var details,pickElements;
    var current_page = 1;
    var records_per_page = 4;
    var taId = parseInt(document.getElementById("taId").value);
    var subjectId;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET','ViewTeacherAndSubject?id='+taId,true);
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if(this.status === 200){
            var infodetails = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            $("#urlsubjectname").html(infodetails.subject.name);
            $("#urlclassname").html(infodetails.subject.classs.name);
            subjectId = parseInt(infodetails.subject.id);
            xhr2.open('GET','ViewStudentsOfferingSubjects?id='+subjectId,true);
            xhr2.onload = function(){
                if(this.status === 200){
                    details = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    renderDisplay(current_page);
                }
            };
            xhr2.send(); 
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
    
    function renderDisplay(page){
        if (page < 1){
            page = 1;
        }
        if (page > numPages()){
            page = numPages();
        }
        let display = "";
        if(details.length> 0){
            $("#totalCount").html(details.length);
            for(var i = (page-1) * records_per_page; i < (page * records_per_page) && i < details.length; i++){
                display += "<tr>"+
                "<td><input type='checkbox' name='studentId' value="+details[i].id+" form='form1' checked></td>"+
                "<td><img src='pictures/"+details[i].image+"' style='width:50px; height:50px;' ></td>"+
                "<td>"+details[i].rollno+"</td>"+
                "<td class='w3-right datatable'><button class='w3-transparent w3-button w3-hover-none w3-padding-small w3-border w3-round-small' style='cursor:pointer' onclick=\"document.getElementById('"+details[i].id+"').classList.toggle('w3-show') \"><img src='images/More_20px_1.png'></button>"+
                "<div class='w3-hide w3-modal' id="+i+">\n\
                <div class='w3-modal-content w3-card-4'>\n\
                <header class='w3-container w3-padding w3-border-bottom'>\n\
                <div class='w3-left w3-large'>Roll Number: "+details[i].rollno+"</div>\n\
                <div class='w3-right'><button class='w3-btn w3-ripple w3-red w3-padding-small w3-round' onclick='document.getElementById("+i+").classList.remove(\"w3-show\") '>x</button></div>\n\
                </header>\n\
                <section class='w3-section w3-center'>\n\
                <div class='w3-responsive'>\n\
                <table>\n\
                <tr><td><a href='#' class='w3-border w3-button'>View Details</a></td></tr>\n\
                </table></div>\n\
                </section>\n\
                </div></div></td>"+
                "</tr>"; 
            }
            $("#page").html(page);
            $("#tbody").html(display);   
        }else{
            display = "<div class='w3-padding-large w3-center'><div class='w3-tag w3-padding w3-round w3-blue w3-text-white'>No Students Added For This Subject</div></div>";
            $("#container").html(display);
        }
        $("#btn_prev").click(function () {
            if (page > 1) {
                page--;
                renderDisplay(page);
            }
        });
        $("#btn_next").click(function () {
            if (page < numPages()) {
                page++;
                renderDisplay(page);
            }
        });
        if (page === 1) {
            $("#btn_prev").addClass("w3-disabled");
        } else {
            $("#btn_prev").removeClass("w3-disabled");
        }

        if (page === numPages()) {
            $("#btn_next").addClass("w3-disabled");
        } else {
            $("#btn_next").removeClass("w3-disabled");
        }
        
    }
    
    function numPages(){
        return Math.ceil(details.length / records_per_page);
    }
    
    $("#search").on("input",searchData);
    
    function searchData(){
        var str = this.value;
        var display ='';
        var page =1;
        if (page < 1){
            page = 1;
        }
        var j = 1;
        pickElements = [];
        str = str.toString().toLowerCase();
        var rollno,pos;
        for(var i=0; i < details.length; i++){
            rollno = details[i].rollno.toLowerCase();
            pos = rollno.search(str);
            if(pos >= 0){
                pickElements.push(details[i]);
                j++;
            }
        }
        $("#totalCount").html(pickElements.length);
        if(pickElements.length < 1){
            display = "<div class='w3-padding w3-center'><div class='w3-tag w3-padding w3-round w3-blue w3-text-white'>No Student Found With That Roll No</div></div>";
            $("#container").html(display);
        }
        for(var i = (page-1) * records_per_page; i < (page * records_per_page) && i < pickElements.length; i++){
            display += "<tr>"+
                "<td><input type='checkbox' name='studentId' value="+pickElements[i].id+" form='form1' checked></td>"+
                "<td><img src='pictures/"+pickElements[i].image+"' style='width:50px; height:50px;' ></td>"+
                "<td>"+pickElements[i].rollno+"</td>"+
                "<td class='w3-right datatable'><button class='w3-transparent w3-button w3-hover-none w3-padding-small w3-border w3-round-small' style='cursor:pointer' onclick=\"document.getElementById('"+i+"').classList.toggle('w3-show') \"><img src='images/More_20px_1.png'></button>"+
                "<div class='w3-hide w3-modal' id="+i+">\n\
                <div class='w3-modal-content w3-card-4'>\n\
                <header class='w3-container w3-padding w3-border-bottom'>\n\
                <div class='w3-left w3-large'>Roll No: "+pickElements[i].rollno+"</div>\n\
                <div class='w3-right'><button class='w3-btn w3-ripple w3-red w3-padding-small w3-round' onclick='document.getElementById("+i+").classList.remove(\"w3-show\") '>x</button></div>\n\
                </header>\n\
                <section class='w3-section w3-center'>\n\
                <div class='w3-responsive'>\n\
                <table>\n\
                <tr><td><a href='teacherviewstudent.jsp?id="+pickElements[i].id+"&classId="+pickElements[i].classs.id+"' class='w3-border w3-button'>View Details</a></td></tr>\n\
                <tr><td><a href='#' class='w3-border w3-button'>View Performance</a></td></tr>\n\
                <tr><td><a href='#' class='w3-border w3-button'>Remove Student</a></td></tr>\n\
                </table></div>\n\
                </section>\n\
                </div></div></td>"+
                "</tr>";       
        }
        $("#page").html(page);
        $("#tbody").html(display);
        
        $("#btn_prev").click(function () {
            if (page > 1) {
                page--;
                renderDisplay(page);
            }
        });
        $("#btn_next").click(function () {
            if (page < (Math.ceil(pickElements.length / records_per_page))) {
                page++;
                renderDisplay(page);
            }
        });
        if (page === 1) {
            $("#btn_prev").addClass("w3-disabled");
        } else {
            $("#btn_prev").removeClass("w3-disabled");
        }
        if((Math.ceil(pickElements.length / records_per_page)) > page){
            page++;
        }
        if (page === 1) {
            $("#btn_next").addClass("w3-disabled");
        } else {
            $("#btn_next").removeClass("w3-disabled");
        }
    }
<!--                            <script>
                                fetch("http://localhost:8080/CBTApplication/ViewClasses").then(
                                        res=>{
                                            res.json().then(
                                            data=>{
                                                console.log(data);
                                            if(data.length > 0){
                                                var temp = "";
                                                var i = 1;
                                                data.forEach((u)=>{
                                                    temp += "<tr>";
                                                    temp += "<td>"+i+"</td>";
                                                    temp += "<td>"+u.name+"</td>";
                                                    temp += "<td><button><img src='images/More_20px_1.png'></button></td>";
                                                    i++;
                                                })
                                                document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML = temp;
                                            }
                                            });
                                        });
                            </script>-->
});
```

and this is a screenshot of what it looks like

[image]

Sorry if the code is messy, thanks for your assistance...